# How to get the correct Sensitivity value when change the meeting from private to not private

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I use EWS managed API “Appointment.Bind” to get the appointment of a meeting room by an Application Impersonation account.

When a meeting's "private" checkbox was unchecked, the property "Sensitivity" of the appointment was 0(normal).
When a meeting's "private" checkbox was checked, the property "Sensitivity" of the appointment was 2(private).
When an existing meeting's "private" checkbox was changed from unchecked to checked, the property "Sensitivity" of the appointment changed from 0 to 2.

But When an existing meeting's "private" checkbox was changed from checked to unchecked, the property "Sensitivity" of the appointment was still 2(0 should be correct).

So how can the Sensitivity value be correct when an existing meeting's "private" checkbox was changed from checked to unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

When the change where made was a Meeting update request sent ? if no meeting updates are sent (which depends on the client) then the attendees and Meeting room mailboxes won't update because these objects aren't linked directly in the Exchange store. Therefore an Attendee/Meeting Room will only ever update based on an update request (not on change of the organizer appointment).

Comment: Sorry that the reply is late.

Comment: When the "private" changed(from checked to unchecked or from unchecked to check), I would receive the notification of the modify event from exchange. It is strange that when "private" changed from unchecked to check, the property "Sensitivity" of the appointment which I got by Item ID from modify event notification was correctly changed from 0 to 2. But "private" changed from checked to unchecked it was uncorrect.

Comment: For more information, I have set the property RemovePrivateProperty of the meeting room to "false" by powershell

Comment: That configuration won't apply to existing appointments so if you want to update existing meetings you will need to do it manually

Comment: My step is 1st.Set the Property RemovePrivateProperty of the meeting room to "false" by powershell. 2nd.Create a meeting on the outlook with "private" unchecked.I receive the notification and the appointment's "Sensitivity" of the meeting room is 0. 3rd.Change this meeting's "private" from unchecked to checked.  I receive the notification and the appointment's "Sensitivity" of the meeting room is 2. 4th.Change this meeting's "private" from checked to unchecked. I receive the notification and the appointment's "Sensitivity" of the meeting room is still 2(Which I think 0 is correct)